Regular singular points of differential equation
I have a little knowledge about regular singular points and how to find these point but for the following differential equation I am little confused, so my question is,  what are the regular singular points of this differential equation:
$$
x^2y''-(x^2+x)y'+y=0?
$$
More precisely, is $x=0$ a regular singular point or not?
